# What does "sudo -s" actually do?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.04

I am using ubuntu 10.04.

I notice that after I run in terminal:

```
sudo -s
```

The prompt changed from:

```
my_user@my_hostname
```

to:

```
root@my_hostname
```

Seems it changed to root privilege.

But when I check the documentation of `sudo` command [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm), it explains another story of `sudo -s`, can anyone explain to me what is `sudo -s` doing exactly?

Comment: You should ask this over at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Why askubuntu.com?  `sudo` is hardly Ubuntu-specific...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between comands "su -s" and "sudo -s"](http://superuser.com/questions/29/difference-between-comands-su-s-and-sudo-s)

Answer (score 12):

The two aren't really inconsistent - the `sudo` command always changes user, either to root, or to the user you specify with the `-u` switch. All the `-s` does is provide a shortcut for starting a shell as that user. It is really equivalent to:

```
sudo $SHELL
```

except that it will likely fallback to `/bin/sh` or something if `SHELL` is not set.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo -s` runs the shell specified in your `$SHELL` environment variable as the superuser/root. You can specify another user using `-u`.

The `$SHELL` environment variable contains the path to the user's default login shell. The actual setting for the default shell program is usually in `etc/passwd`. Depending on what you've done in your current session, the `$SHELL` variable may not contain the shell program you're currently using. If you login automatically with `zsh` for instance, but then invoke bash, `$SHELL` won't change from `/bin/zsh`.

Show the current user and shell program:

```
echo $(whoami) is logged in and shell is $0
```

- `whoami` prints out the username the user is working under.
- `$0` contains the name/path of the currently running program (shell program in this case).

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the sudoers file.

> -s    Shell, runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is
> set or the shell as specified in passwd(5).

More seriously, the `sudo -s` run a shell environment variable. Since you didn't add any variable it run as specified in `passwd`, and so connect you as root.

Comment: It is not obvious from the manual that if you don't provide a user, it defaults to root. You would have to read the description for `-u` option to learn that. But for someone who is not familiar with `sudo`, they wouldn't know to look at `-u`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post from superuser:

[What's the difference between the commands "su -s" and "sudo -s"?](https://superuser.com/questions/29/difference-between-comands-su-s-and-sudo-s#42)

By the way, your post should be moved to superuser (or askubuntu as said in comments)!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is creating another instance of the shell on top of the current shell, but with root privileges.  I'll bet that after you do `sudo -s` if you type exit, you will go back to the original shell.